# Tell me hint, $\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac{i}{\left( n+1\right) \left( n+2\right) }$

Tags: summation, infinity

I want to solve this.
$$\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac{i}{\left( n+1\right) \left( n+2\right) }$$
Answer is $\dfrac{i}{2}$.

I don't know how to solve this. Please tell me hint.

Comment: Hint:  expand your expression in partial fractions.

Comment: Ok. Hint: Telescoping series.

Comment: Telescoping sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{(n+1)}-\frac{1}{(n+2)}
$$

Comment: I can solve this. Thank you very much.